# Qt [PySide6] visual artefacts with custom paintEvent

Tags: pyside6

I'm trying to have a custom painting of a pyqtgraph derived Plot widget (the code is found here https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/blob/bfa09d0b46f1b4b98b9ad1d0a0bb90cbb876b43e/asammdf/gui/widgets/plot.py#L4271): since painting a Plot with thousands of curves is very expensive I want to store the result in a QPixmap, then if I have a cursor active (implemented using an InfiteLine (see https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/6ed7d4fa4762aaa895f7e9b2fb09ec6df4cc793f/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/InfiniteLine.py#L16) I would first draw the QPixmap on the viewport then on top just the cursor item. This way moving the cursor would not trigger the repaint of all the curves.

The QPixmap looks like this

[image]

and this is what happens when I create a cursor and slide it around:

[image]

Note that at the end the plot is zoomed out, this causes the reset of the QPixmap and the "native" repaint which produces the correct image with the single vertical line of the cursor.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be that the paint events were set to update just certain regions of the viewport instead of the full viewport.

The fix was to set the viewport update mode to full update

```
self.setViewportUpdateMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.FullViewportUpdate)
```